# Android Bluetooth speed issue

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'am developing a client app for reading data from CSR board through SPP(RFCOMM channel). I used a sample app from Android SDK (Bluetooth chat) for this purpose, and it works fine for small amounts of data. But when I stream a music from board to the device, the delay appears. I measured a delay in while loop where we are reading from InputStream connected to Bluetooth socket and noticed a interesting moment - the delay is big only for some iterations of loop, but for others the delay is very small - like 0-10 ms. Maybe someone know why it happens? And how can I fix this issue?

Here is a code:

```
public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    int byteCount = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    Log.d("unique_time", (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTime) + " " + byteCount);
                    lastTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

And sample logs (first number - delta time in ms, second one - read bytes):

```
03-23 14:45:16.481  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 491 884
03-23 14:45:16.491  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2 140
03-23 14:45:16.491  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 8 884
03-23 14:45:19.481  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2985 884
03-23 14:45:19.491  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 7 884
03-23 14:45:19.491  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2 214
03-23 14:45:19.501  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 12 884
03-23 14:45:19.501  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2 140
03-23 14:45:19.511  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 7 884
03-23 14:45:19.511  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 1 74
03-23 14:45:19.531  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 21 884
03-23 14:45:19.531  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2 140
03-23 14:45:19.551  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 11 884
03-23 14:45:19.551  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 6 884
03-23 14:45:19.561  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 7 884
03-23 14:45:19.561  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 1 214
03-23 14:45:19.571  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 11 884
03-23 14:45:19.581  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 6 884
03-23 14:45:19.581  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 1 214
03-23 14:45:19.591  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 7 884
03-23 14:45:19.591  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 6 884
03-23 14:45:19.591  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2 214
03-23 14:45:19.601  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 7 884
03-23 14:45:19.661  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 57 884
03-23 14:45:19.661  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2 214
03-23 14:45:19.671  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 6 884
03-23 14:45:19.671  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 6 884
03-23 14:45:19.681  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2 214
03-23 14:45:19.681  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 6 884
03-23 14:45:19.691  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 6 884
03-23 14:45:19.691  24432-25373/coderivium.sbctest D/unique_time﹕ 2 204
```

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14524866/android-bluetooth-serial-rfcomm-low-baud-rate-slow-transmission and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257260/android-bluetooth-slow-data-rates-calculated-from-bluetoothsocket

Comment: Thanks! But what about delays? Why does speed varies so significantly?

Comment: I haven't really used Bluetooth enough to answer, but I'm guessing it has something to do with packet size from your board to device. Hopefully someone with more experience can chime in. Maybe the garbage collector is kicking in for your while loop?

Comment: Thank you once more! Your comment is very helpful. I received packets of size from 400 to 1200 bytes.

Comment: You call System.currentTimeMillis() twice for one time measurement. That looks not ok. Call it once and save in a long. Then use that long twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Really it was an issue with a board. I developed a client application for reading a stream data from the CSR dev board and I noticed that it needs a special bluetooth antenna. When I connected it, the speed improved and delays decreased.